# For all $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ if $\vert X\vert=n$ and $\vert Y\vert=m$, then $\vert X\times Y\vert=nm$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been studying some basic set theory on my own and as I solved exercises I stumbled upon the statement in the title. At first glance it seems pretty obvious that it should be true. But this is set theory, nothing is obvious. So I went ahead and started working on a proof. My first instinct was to use double induction, but after I completed the argument I noticed it didn't seem to be necessary. What I mean by this is that the induction over $n$ seems completely redundant; the proof can be completed without having to use the inductive hypothesis. I thought this was a bit odd so I would like to have the argument checked by other people. This is what I came up with:

Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $\vert X\vert=n$. We will use induction on $m$. If $\vert Y\vert=0$. Then $Y=\emptyset$ and as a result $X\times Y=X\times\emptyset=\emptyset$. Therefore, $\vert X\times Y\vert=0=n0$, by the recursive definition of multiplication. Suppose now that for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and all $Y$ such that $\vert Y\vert=k$, $\vert X\times Y\vert=nk$. Let $Y$ be such that $\vert Y\vert=k+1$. By definition, this equality means that there exists a bijective map from $n$ to $Y$ (in particular this map is injective). So we can enumerate the elements of Y and write $Y=\lbrace y_{0},...,y_{k}\rbrace$. Now define $Y'=Y\setminus\lbrace y_{k}\rbrace$. Clearly $\vert Y'\vert=k$, so we can apply the inductive hypothesis.

Before that, we need to make some observations. First, by elementary properties of sets we know that $X\times Y=(X\times Y')\cup(X\times\lbrace y_{0}\rbrace)$. Second, the book I'm following also proves that if A and B are finite and disjoint then $\vert A\cup B\vert=\vert A\vert+\vert B\vert$. Applying this result with $A=X\times Y'$ and $B=X\times\lbrace y_{0}\rbrace$, yields the equality $\vert(X\times Y')\cup(X\times\lbrace y_{0}\rbrace)\vert=\vert X\times Y'\vert\cup\vert X\times\lbrace y_{0}\rbrace\vert$. Third, we can easily define a bijection between $X\times\lbrace y_{0}\rbrace$ and $X$, thus showing that $\vert X\times\lbrace y_{0}\rbrace\vert=n$. Finally, we apply the inductive hypothesis to $\vert X\times Y'\vert$ to conclude that the cardinal of this set is $nk$.

So far, we have proved that $\vert X\times Y\vert=nk+n$. By the recursive definition of multiplication we know that the right hand side equals $n(k+1)$. By the principle of mathematical induction, the statement is true for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Now, even though $n$ was fixed, it was arbitrary. So we arrive at the conclusion. That is, for all $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ if $\vert X\vert=n$ and $\vert Y\vert=m$, then $\vert X\times Y\vert=nm$. This last step might seem sketchy, but as far as I know it's just an instance of the rule of generalization from first order logic.

Comment: It looks like correct but honestly, I do not read your idea analysing all the details, but you can show that statement by showing an existence of a bijections between $X \times Y \to I_{nm}$ where $I_{nm} = \{1,...,nm\}$. The cardinality of a finite set can be defined by a bijection between $I_n$ and $X$; in that case we say that $|X| = n$.

Comment: @Corrêa Yes, I also considered the possibility of constructing the bijection explicitly by first enumerating all the elements of $X$ and $Y$ (say, $x_{0},...,x_{n-1}$ and $y_{0},...y_{m-1}$) and then simply defining the function that maps the pair $(x_{i}, y_{j})$ to ij. I'm interested in checking the proof by induction because it seems strange that I can bypass the induction on n completely. I mean, you can do the induction anyway, but it only takes up space and makes the proof way harder to follow. At least I couldn't find the point in the argument where it's necessary.

Comment: @ModestoRosado I think you need to use double induction to be as precise as possible. The last part you find a little sketchy would be the second inductive step.

Comment: @GVT I have an earlier version of the proof that includes the induction over the second variable, but the thing is that the inductive step doesn't use the inductive hypothesis. At all. That's why I think it's unnecesary and redundant. I don't find the last step sketchy. It might seem sketchy to others, but the way I see it, it's just an instance of a valid rule of inference: namely, if $P(y)$ then $(\forall x)(P(x))$.

Comment: @GVT At least I don't see where the inductive hypothesis is used in the second induction.